# How to view the python command triggered when an action happens in 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting

In Blender 2.7 you could drag down the info area and view all the python commands that are being executing when you run an action.

[image]

How can you do the same with Blender 2.8+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just go to any window (I use the timeline so long as I'm not animating), and select "info" as the editor type.

[image: Info1]

The information should appear as you expect.

[image: Info2]